# Difference between geographic, geometric data and spatial data?

Tags: database, spatial, geography

I would like to know what the difference is between geographic data, geometric data and standard type of data representing of spatial data in database system (for example in Oracle or SqlSqerver)?

For me it looks like the same, but I know that there must be a difference. 
.

Comment: I think you need to define (preferably with examples) of what you mean by 'geographic/geometric data' for anyone to have a chance of answering this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Geographic data and Geometric data are `not same`. But when you are using those data in application, both will looks same (As per your assumption) . But In real, both has unique meaning. Let me explain,

---

**Geographic Data :**

Geographic data is simply a collection of information that can describe objects and things with relation to space (Here space stands for position). Often this is done with x,y coordinates or longitudes and latitudes.

```
So Geographical Data is simply Longitude and Latitude.
```

---

**Geometric Data :**

Geometry deals with mathematical properties (topology, metric, order). By these properties we could analyze the data. Simply says, It will refer to geometrical shapes in the application.

```
So Geometric Data is simply mathematical properties (topology, metric, order)
```

- geometric information enables the users to maintain a consistent geographic database and to ask complex spatial queries. Hope Now, you could understand it in better way.

---

**Spatial Data :**

Spatial data refers the geographic location of features and boundaries on Earth, such as natural or constructed features, oceans, and more. Spatial data is usually stored as coordinates and topology, and is data that can be mapped.

Even you could have think Spatial data refers to shapes(Polygon, polyline, circle, etc.) in a Geographical information with geometric data.

```
So Spatial Data is a mixture of Geometrical data and Geographical data.
```

**Practical Example with Application :**

A Country / State / City boundries consist of multiple longitude and latitude. To separate or distinct with other Country / State / City, have to represent a Country / State / City with boundries with the help of polygon shape.

So, Geographic and Geometric data is tightly coupled together in terms of spatial application.